# Open cell range in read_excel R

Tags: r, excel

Is there a way to not specify a cell range in the `read_excel` function in R?

So, for example, if the data entries start at cell C3 and end at cell D300, could I not be forced to specify D300, but instead tell R to read until there are no more cells with data entries in them?

Something like:

```
A <- read_excel("excell/book.xlsx", sheet="A", range="C3:")
```

Comment: One strategy would be to over-read and then drop empty rows/columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the docs for `readxl::read_excel`, it includes

```
range: A cell range to read from, as described in
       cell-specification. Includes typical Excel ranges like
       "B3:D87", possibly including the sheet name like
       "Budget!B2:G14", and more. Interpreted strictly, even if the
       range forces the inclusion of leading or trailing empty rows
       or columns. Takes precedence over 'skip', 'n_max' and
       'sheet'.
```

Though it is easy to assume it must be a string, if you dig into `?readxl::cell-specification`, it suggests you look into `cellranger::cell_limits()`. In that, it says that

```
cell_limits(ul = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_), lr = c(NA_integer_,
  NA_integer_), sheet = NA_character_)
...
A value of 'NA' in 'ul' or 'lr' means the corresponding limit is left unspecified.
```

This says that you can use `NA` to leave things open.

Try:

```
A <- read_excel("excell/book.xlsx", sheet="A", range=cellranger::cell_limits(c(3,3)))
```

where an unspecified `lr` leaves the lower-right corner open.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
A <- read_exel("excell/book.xlsx", sheet = "A", range = cell_limits(c(3, 3), c(NA, NA))
```

see here for more information: https://readxl.tidyverse.org/reference/cell-specification.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).